# Regex for Email Address along with name format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For email address I am using regex as

var emailRegex = /^([\w-.]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/

What is regex for

```
LastName FirstName <lastName.firstName@gmail.com>
```

Comment: there isn't any perfect regex for an email ID.

Comment: Same as [Lname FName<lName.fName@xxx.com>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299372/regex-expression-for-email-address) which in also seems to be duplicate [Regex for email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Check out the regexp used to validate email addresses according to the RFC 822 grammar: [Don't actually use this](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Use backrefs:

```
/^([\w-.]+) ([\w-.]+) (\1\.\2@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
```